# Register Flash Message in laravel 5.3 provided auth

Tags: laravel, session, authentication

I want to flash a screen when a user registers.

Now I know this is doable with a flash session which should be just before the redirect. However I can't find the redirect to my page when the user registers, I can only change the place redirected to with a a variable. Where should I put my flash session code?

I tried to put the flash inside the create function however that also does not seem to work;

protected function create(array $data)

```
{
    Session::flash('success', 'User successfully created.');
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'company' => $data['company'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

I try to call the flash with this code:

```
  @if (session('succes'))
    <h3>{{ Session::get('succes') }}</h3>
  @endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled "succes" in the second code snippet.

```
@if (session('success'))
   <h3>{{ Session::get('success') }}</h3>
@endif
```

... should do it